# How it is possible to be a circle in python?

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics

Here is the code In the book Thinkpython 2e.

```
 import turtle
 import math

 bob = turtle.Turtle()

 def polygon(t, n, length):
     angle = 360 / n
     for i in range(n):
         t.fd(length)
         t.lt(angle)    

 def circle(t, r):
     circumference = 2 * math.pi * r
     n = 50
     length = circumference / n
     polygon(t, n, length)

 circle(bob,50)
 turtle.mainloop()
```

I don't understand how it is possible to be a circle, I think it will be a 50-sides polygon, am i right?

Comment: it is 50-sides polygon but it looks almost like circle.

Comment: Note that's where comments and docstring are useful, ideally you'd have some info like `"""approximate a circle with a regular 50-gone"""` to break the confusion...

Answer (score 4):

A circle has infinitely many points, a screen has finitely many pixels. You are correct that you can't draw true circles on a screen. This isn't to say that drawing a polygon is the only way to approximate a circle on the screen. As @Qwerty rightly points out in the comments you can also do so with trig functions.

Nevertheless, approximating circles by polygons is an ancient approach and was the classical way in which pi was approximated. Also -- it is a fun exercise for turtles.

Comment: You can use SINE and COSINE to draw about as close as you can get to a circle on a computer

Comment: @Qwerty Good point. I'll edit my post so as to not give the impression that drawing a polygon is the only way to approximate a circle.

Comment: Would you like me to post the math?

Comment: @Qwerty No need, basic polar coordinates, although it might be interesting if you can show how to do it with the Python turtle module.

Comment: Looks like somebody got to it before me

Comment: The most accurate and the fastest algorithm to draw pixelized circles is called Midpoint Circle Algorithm, and it has a Python implementation: https://gist.github.com/0xKD/4530035

Answer (score 1):

I have not programmed in python in a while (specifically with the turtle libraries) but if I remember, there is a way easier

```
import turtle

circumfrence = 80

turtle = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.shape("circle")
turtle.circle(circumfrence / 2)
```

It's that Simple!

Comment: This may be a simple way to do  this but its hard to work with to make an ellipse. Using SINE and COSINE would be more powerful but maybe more confusing to some people who haven't studies trigonometry. But, this answer suits this persons needs. Good Work!

Comment: It's simple but incorrect.  The Python `turtle.circle()` method takes a radius which is `diameter / 2` or `circumference / (2 * math.pi)`.  That's basic math, not Python.

Comment: cdlane, I would like to ask you a question... what is the topic about? cause it is on how to be a circle, and the drawing a circle was only an example!

Comment: I'd say the question is along the lines, "if a polygon has sufficient sides that it looks like a circle, does that really make it a circle?"  Your `turtle.shape("circle")` cursor doesn't address the question and your `turtle.circle(circumfrence / 2)` has badly named variables (should be `diameter / 2` as `turtle.circle()` takes a radius, and is a polygon with lots of sides, not calculated like a true circle using `sin()` and `cos()`.

Comment: in that case, why did they add it that way?

Answer (score 0):

The odd part about your `circle()` function to me is that `n` is fixed at 50.  At the extremes of large and small circles, this might not be optimal and maybe should be more dynamic.  As far as a 50-sided polygon vs. a circle, let's test using the `turtle.circle()` command:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

radius = 100
sides = 50

bob = Turtle(shape="turtle")
bob.width(2)

bob.pencolor("red")
bob.circle(radius)

bob.pencolor("green")
bob.circle(radius, steps=sides)

bob.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

The `turtle.circle()` method uses a polygon approximation but it computes the number of sides as a function of the radius with a maxium of 60. For the radius of 100 above, it actually uses only 28 steps so our 50-sided polygon is potentially ***more*** accurate!

Comment: the circle part is only an example... we are talking about how to turn into a circle!

Comment: @BukkitmanPlaysMCPE, I don't understand your comment.  Please rephrase as it may shed light on this discussion.

Comment: nvm that, but can you recreate the script, but instead have the circles separate from each other?